# Healthcheck failing to Reference Data service with 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: xconnect, health-monitor

I am using the [/healthz/ready endpoint](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/101/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/monitoring-the-health-of-web-roles.html) on Azure PaaS XP Scaled, and seeing this healthcheck fail:

> Health check Sitecore.Xdb.ReferenceData.Client.ReadOnlyReferenceDataHttpClient completed after 52.7561ms with status Unhealthy and 'Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).'

I know that the reference data service is in fact working fine - Marketing Automation / Reporting is all functional.

The RefData server web logs show:

```
2021-06-09 01:00:40 xyz POST /refdata/definition/get latestActiveOnly=False&X-ARR-LOG-ID=fd8bf61e-2831-40f6-b5e0-4491f50f9ceb 443 - <CD Server IP>  - xyz.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 1551 2542 0
2021-06-09 01:00:00 xyz GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=b62df60a-7412-4024-86e5-146405dd0522 443 - <CD Server IP>  - xyz.azurewebsites.net 403 14 0 415 2181 15
```

So I can see that any POST (also PUT) are working with a 200 / 201 response, but a simple GET on the root is failing with 403.

Other things I have checked:

- `AllowInvalidClientCertificates=True` on all servers
- The client certificate is valid
- IP is whitelisted (removed all IP restrictions to confirm it is not an IP issue)

Sitecore XP 10.0.0

Comment: Does it work if you just call the refData url from your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore support advised:

The issue is a bug with reference number 439986.

As a workaround for the issue, please try adding the following section:

```
</security>
<defaultDocument>
<files>
<clear />
<add value="Default.aspx" />
</files>
</defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

in the "web.config" file of the following web apps:

- -xc-search
- -xc-refdata
- -xc-collect
- -ma-rep
- -ma-ops

I have confirmed this has fixed the issue.